# Form uploads a file once, but it doesn't work on the same file when I upload the same file again

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I can upload a file from the form below, selecting a file from the file chooser. But the problem is when I try to submit the form with the same file again, it doesn't do anything.

I choose a file from the file chooser, upload it. I choose the same file again, then I can't upload it again. But if I upload the file after I try a different file, then I can upload the same file again.

What is wrong with the codes below.

I have included jquery for the script and html for the form. I don't really understand what's going wrong with them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datauploadbtn").on('click', function() {
    $('#datafile').trigger('click');
  });

  $('#datafile').change(function(e) {
    //var reg=/(.txt)$/;
    //if (!reg.test($("#myFile").val())) {
    // alert('Only .txt file extension allowed!');
    //    return false;
    //} else {
    $("#datafiletxt").val($("#datafile").val());
    if ($("#datafiletxt").val() == '') {
      alert('Select a file to upload');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#dataform').submit();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });


});



$(function() {
  var bar = $('.barTest');
  var percent = $('.percentTest');
  var status = $('#statusTest');

  $('#dataform').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#percentTest').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $('#percentTest').css('color', ' white');
      $('#barTest').css('background-color', 'white');
      $('#statusTest').css('color', 'white');
      $('#progressTest').css('border', '1px solid white');
      $('#percentSpan').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $('#statusSpan').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      //status.empty();
      alert('Successfully uploaded!');
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#percentTest').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('#percentTest').css('color', ' black');
      $('#barTest').css('background-color', '#B4F5B4');
      $('#statusTest').css('color', 'orange');
      $('#progressTest').css('border', '1px solid #ddd');
      $('#percentSpan').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('#statusSpan').css('visibility', 'visible');
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal)
      percent.html(percentVal);
      console.log(percentVal);
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ajaxasync" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="dataform" id="dataform">
  <input type="button" value="Data file" id="datauploadbtn" name="datauploadbtn" style="width:100px; font:12px 'Arial'; font-weight:bold; height:30px; background:lightblue;" />
  <input type="text" id="datafiletxt" style="width:260px; font:12px 'Arial'; font-weight:bold; height:27px;" />
  <input type="file" name="datafile" id="datafile" style="visibility:hidden;" />
</form>

<div id="progressTest" class="progressTest">
 <div id="barTest" class="barTest"></div >
 <div id="percentTest" class="percentTest" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
</div>

<div id="statusTest" style="font:11px 'Arial'; color: orange;">
 <span id="statusSpan" style="visibility:hidden;">
  File uploading in progress... <br>
  Please wait!
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is most likely a caching issue. I suggest you check the response code of the second request in your browsers debugging console. Most likely you will get something like "not altered", thus the same request is not send again. In that case you have to add http headers to the reply, which prevent the response from being cached.

Comment: I tried Chrome console, but I don't see anything. Can you tell me what http header is?

Comment: May I suggest that you simply start reading some documentation about "http headers"?

Comment: You can tell me what it is

Comment: The problem is fixed. It had nothing to do with http header.

Answer (score 0):

You currently using ON CHANGE event. If you select same file the value will still remain constant. So that mean you need to change the value to empty once you grab the value form the on change event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datauploadbtn").on('click', function() {
    $('#datafile').trigger('click');
  });

  $('#datafile').change(function(e) {
    //var reg=/(.txt)$/;
    //if (!reg.test($("#myFile").val())) {
    //  alert('Only .txt file extension allowed!');
    //    return false;
    //} else {
    $("#datafiletxt").val($("#datafile").val());
    if ($("#datafiletxt").val() == '') {
      alert('Select a file to upload');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('#dataform').submit();
      e.preventDefault();
    }






    $("#datafile").val("");//this is the changd!!!





  });


});
```

I comment the code you need to insert

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading a file via ajax the input values and the file are still on the form you must clear the form `$('#dataform')[0].reset();` or clear the value of the input `$("#datafiletxt").val("");` which triggers the upload button.